# Can a function(event) variable not permanently change the contents of an instance variable?

Tags: javascript

I have an object that has a function that reads information into an array.

I call an instance of the object to open a file, it reads the information into  `RAWDATA:[]`.

I then call the function `doSomething` however `RAWDATA[1].length` is undefined

if this is not a syntactical error does this mean that a an event function such as below cannot permanently affect the objects variables?

```
var object{
             RAWDATA:[],
             openFile: function (event) {

                var input = event.target;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function () {
                    var dataURL = reader.result;

                    console.log(dataURL);
                    this.RAWDATA = dataURL.split(",");
                    this.NEWDATA = this.RAWDATA[1];

                    alert("raw data length "+this.RAWDATA[1].length);


                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

            },doSomething: function(){
             console.log(this.RAWDATA[1].length);
             alert("raw data length "+this.RAWDATA[1].length);
 }
```

Comment: When are you calling `doSomething`? If you call `doSomething` without calling `openfile` then `RAWDATA` will be empty.

Comment: as per the above I call object.openFile, then later call   object.doSomething

Comment: Likely also a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback, but I felt the async issue was more problematic (when is "later"?).

Comment: While it had occurred to me that it could be related to an async issue @dan08 is more correct imo as it was a scope of 'this' issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the ever frustrating `this` scope problem.

In your case when you are setting `this.RAWDATA` inside the `reader.onload` function. `this` refers to the FileReader object.

To solve the problem set `var self = this` at the beginning of `openFile`, and then use self when referring to the "object" object

Comment: This was the root cause of the frustration, I attempted to deal with the instance with the use of this and neglected the new scope of the internal function